# React JS array forEach get refs value using variable

Tags: reactjs

How can i get this to work correctly using this method below? I need to go through each value in the array

```
array.forEach((v) => {
   let a = `this.refs.a${v}.value`
   console.log(a) // prints this.refs.a0.value
   console.log(this.refs.a0.value) // prints correct value 
})
```

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to access refs by name. In JavaScript you can access object's property using `object[propertyName]` syntax, where the property name is a string.
Using this method you can rewrite your property access to `` this.refs[`a${v}`].value ``.

So the final code should look like this:

```
array.forEach((v) => {
   let r = this.refs[`a${v}`].value
   console.log(r) // prints correct value
})
```

Comment: Working perfect. Thanks!